# Curl not installed correctly (Call to undefined function curl_init())

Tags: php, linux, curl, ubuntu-server

I have installed curl on my ubuntu server 14.04,

On the file:

```
/etc/php5/mods-available/curl.ini
```

I have this

```
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/curl.so
```

On PHP ini file

```
extension=curl.so
```

But when I run something like this

```
var_dump(extension_loaded('curl'));
```

returns false, and obviously, in php application is not working neither.

Comment: did you restart apache?

Comment: yes, and still not working

Comment: Did you tried to run `php5enmod curl` ?

Comment: Yes @FilipMatthew and still not working

Answer (score 0):

if you are using WAMP is very important to remove the semicolon from both php.ini files.

Because one from apache folder is to the web and the another one, that is in the PHP folder is for the command line.

Regards.

Comment: You can executa a php file with the follow content: <?php phpinfo(); ?> and then, you can see if really exists. And also, please, publis some information about you system (SO, architecture, etc) Regards!

Comment: You can see the php information here: http://www.americainmobiliaria.com/info.php but the point is, curl is not recognized, and the configuration is apparently ok